# Wordpress: Host Images To Server From Link

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Recently, I import all post from blogger to wordpress. In each post there are images displaying. I wanna get all those images and store it on my server and change all those image url to new one automatically as post amount is big.

Please guide me how to do this or redirect me to a plugin that does the job. I did my research and could not find any plugin for this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this plugin will do the job, Untested:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogger-image-import/

**Description:**

> This plugin searches your blog posts for images that are hosted on
>   Blogger (blogger.com or blogspot.com), downloads them to your server,
>   and updates your posts to refer to the downloaded versions.

Comment: Amazing !!! That Worked . I would never find that plugin because of its irrelevant title.

Comment: I actually typed in google `wordpress import blogger images` ;) n first result...